# Update a variable value on .bat file from powershell output (invoked on same .bat)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Have the following code and wanted the result from powershell to be in aux_var.
(regular .bat file invoked from cmd)

```
@echo off
set aux=123.657.999
echo before%aux%
powershell -Command "'%aux%' -replace '\.',''"
echo after%aux%
```

Result

```
before123.657.999
123657999
after123.657.999
```

Obvious that the code do not update the result because I do not know how to grab the powershell result.

Desired Result

```
before123.657.999
after123657999
```

Till now didn't find something usefull.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In PowerShell the empty replacement string `,''` can be omitted with the `-replace` operator (while the .replace() method needs it)

Comment: Thx. @LotPings,  good to know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a standalone to achieve what you want, but if you really want to use both `batch` and `powershell`

```
@echo off
set aux=123.657.999
echo before%aux%
for /f %%i in ('powershell -Command "'%aux%' -replace '\.',''"') do set aux=%%i
echo after%aux%
```

PS!! an exact method using pure batch would be:

```
@echo off
set aux=123.657.999
echo before%aux%
set aux=%aux:.=%
echo after%aux%
```

Comment: this is what i founded for the moment since batch have limited functions. Since more functions on power shell, that could be a good mix for future.

Comment: No problem, it is just an observation :)

Comment: kindly, look again because value is not update the aux var. Just echo locally.Need aux to be updated and is not.

Comment: for /f %%i in ('powershell -Command "'%aux%' -replace '\.',''"') do set aux=%%i

Comment: updated the answer, that was just an example, you need to set the new variable.

Comment: yes, credit the answer. Very new to batch and powershell cmd

Comment: by the way.. you can run pure batch for that much simpler... will add to answer.

Comment: pls. it could help me.

Comment: added to answer. That is a simple search and replace in batch.